# XPATH- How to select radio button and text in a single xpath expression?

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver

I have Radio button with value as "`CREDIT_CARD`" and the text of the radio button as "`New`". Now i need to select a radio button which has text "New".

```
<div>
<input type="radio" onchange="javascript:toggleAdvancedDisplay('pay_detail','CREDIT_CARD');" value="CREDIT_CARD" name="payment_type" style="margin:0; vertical-align: middle;"/>
<span class="value">New</span>
```

I tried the below xpath, but it doesn't locate the expected element.

```
/fieldset[1]/div/div/div[2]/input[@value='CREDIT_CARD']/fieldset[1]/div/div/div[2]/span[contains(text(), 'New')]
```

What is it i am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try :

```
xpath = //input[@value='CREDIT_CARD' and following-sibling::span[contains(., 'New')]]
```

This will get input tag with `CREDIT_CARD` as value and whose sibling contains `New` as text.

Answer (score 2):

The `<span>` element is not a child of the `<input>` element, but it is the next sibling. XPath should be:

```
/fieldset[1]/div/div/div[2]/input[@value='CREDIT_CARD' and following-sibling::span[1] = 'New']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Does this locate the element you're looking for?

```
xpath = //*[@value="CREDIT_CARD"]/span[contains(.,"New")]
```

Comment: No, it's not locating the element i'm looking for.